# Baggage restrictions

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage

I am traveling back to Ireland from India next week through gulf air. Just wondering how many cartons of cigarettes am I allowed to carry with me and also is it possible for me to carry cricket bat in its bag along with my laptop bag ? Or should I keep it in check in baggage?
Please let me know the possible ways. Thanks in advance

Comment: Will need to check this up but I recall it is 2 cartons.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to consult with your carrier to determine whether your bat would be allowed in the cabin.

> [**Gulf Air**](https://www.gulfair.com/baggage/special-baggage) has the pleasure in carrying your Special baggage, sporting equipment or musical instruments as part of your free baggage allowance. Normal excess baggage charges will apply if you exceed your free allowance. Each item must not exceed the maximum single piece weight of 32 kg or the following dimensions 190 cm (79in) x 75 cm (29.5in) x 65 cm (25.5in).
>
> [**Duty-free limits**](http://www.ireland.com/about-ireland/travel-information/customs-and-borders/)
>
> If you're arriving in Ireland from outside the EU, you can bring in [certain goods free of duty](http://www.revenue.ie/en/importing-vehicles-duty-free-allowances/customs-information-for-travelling-and-duty-free-allowances/index.aspx) subject to these limits:
>
> - 200 cigarettes or 100 cigarillos or 50 cigars or 250g of smoking tobacco (Allowances are on a fractional basis, for example 100 cigarettes plus 50 cigarillos would be the limit together.)
> - 1 litre of spirits (more than 22%) or 2 litres of intermediate products (e.g. port, sherry, etc. but not sparkling wine)
> - 4 litres of wine or 16 litres of beer
> - 50g of perfume and 250ml of eau de toilette
>
> Customs duty, excise duty and VAT (sales tax), where applicable, are charged on goods in excess of the duty-free allowances.